# Use StructureMap with WCF 4.0 REST Services

Tags: structuremap, wcf-rest

How do I use StructureMap in a WCF 4.0 REST service?

I've used StructureMap in the past using [this article](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/07/29/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf.aspx) but the technique doesn't seem to work with the `WebServiceHostFactory()`. What's the secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work following [this example](http://stillpearling.blogspot.com/2010/07/dependency-injection-using-munq.html). Essentially you write a customer `BehaviorExtension` instead of a `ServiceHostFactory` and life is good.

Would still appreciate any understanding as to why using a custom `WebServiceHostFactory` doesn't work. It appeared to wire everything up correctly but my `IInstanceProvider`'s `GetInstance()` method was never being called.

Answer (score 3):

The method in the previous [example article](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/07/29/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf.aspx) can be made to work by:

- deriving `StructureMapServiceHost` from `WebServiceHost` and **not** `ServiceHost`
- deriving `StructureMapServiceHostFactory` from `WebServiceHostFactory` and **not** `ServiceHostFactory`

The benefit of this? No *web.config* changes required. It's all done programatically.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Alex's instruction, you need to wire up your `ServiceHostFactory` in the service route of your service instead of using `WebServiceHostFactory`.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MemberProvisioning/Api", new IoCServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MemberService)));
```

Hope this helps.